# Ubuntu thinks my desktop is a laptop

Tags: 12.04

Ubuntu thinks my desktop is a laptop. I looked for answers on the interweb, but nada. I'm running 12.04.

Comment: What do you mean it thinks your desktop is a laptop? There isn't any difference in the interface between a desktop and a laptop.

Comment: @tgm4883 one interface difference would be the battery monitor.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? Do you have a UPS plugged in?

Comment: how did you know that Ubuntu thinks your desktop is a laptop?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking under "Displays" and you see this then it is a bug in the system and you don't have anything to worry about. Ubuntu doesn't run any different on a Desktop than on a Laptop anyway. (Besides the differences in hardware affecting the OS ergo RAM, HDD, ETC.)